# android data encoding

Tags: android, encoding

I am creating an android application which allows user to submit some reviews on items. How can I send this review in HTTPRequest (POST method)?
Also I would like to do some kind of encoding before i send out any information. What are the encoding options available in android?

Any exmaple would be really helpful.

Rgds,
Sapan

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.util.Base64;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "this is a message by frank.";
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(data.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        System.out.println("Encoded: " + encoded);

        String decoded = new String(Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT));
        System.out.println("Decoded: " + decoded);
    }
}
```

The output is:

Encoded: `dGhpcyBpcyBhIG1lc3NhZ2UgYnkgZnJhbmsu`

Decoded: `this is a message by frank.`

Let’s try decode the message in python:

```
import base64
print base64.b64decode('dGhpcyBpcyBhIG1lc3NhZ2UgYnkgZnJhbmsu')
```

Comment: show this link i hope your requirement should be complied.         http://www.frankdu.com/notes/2011/01/27/base64-encoding-with-android-2-1-or-earlier/

Answer (score 0):

Using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient and org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
you can send/receive http req/resp in android.
For more detail and example see [Android - A Quick and Dirty Http Client](http://remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a20/Android-A-Quick-and-Dirty-Http-Client.html)

for decoding you can user base64

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you meant marshaling into DOM, you might want to use [JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html). This class provides a bunch of methods for easily creating json trees for sending the data to a server. JSON is usually a bit faster and requires less characters than XML.